# How to share data between Angular Material Bottom Sheet to its parent using additional method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I;m implementing Angular Material Bottom Sheet to my Angular project.
Here is example provided by official Angular Material website.
[Official StackBlitz Page](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qymepxrnxyj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbottom-sheet-overview-example.ts)

What I want to acheive:

1. In `BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet` I added additional function `manipulate()`
2. After I executed above function I want to send data from `BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet` to `BottomSheetOverviewExample`

I don't want to use built in BottomSheet ref because none of them fits to my scenario.

I tried using `@Output` and `EventEmitter` but it doesn't work.

Can you suggest some solution, please?

At the end I want to have badge on button and update this badge from BottomSheet

**UPDATE:**

Here is a link for solution to show that `Output` with `EventEmitter` doesn't work:

[Example with Output and EventEmitter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twsayx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet.html)

Comment: Please provide tried code and if possible then provide stackblitz demo

Comment: EventEmitters work perfect every time. I like to use event sevice because the service creates the event to each component when imported. This means any subscriber or emitter automatically have a communications link. https://dev.to/jwp/the-angular-event-service-ech

Comment: I know but EventEmitters with Output doaesn't work with material bottom sheet for some reason. You could try add EventEmitter with Output to StackBiltz

Comment: @PrashantPimpale added

Comment: @Sepcio You must read about how the `Output` decorator works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@Output`](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) must be used with a parent-child relationship, you can use Shared service is the best option for your situation:

Create one service (Shared.Service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  change =  new Subject<number>();

  constructor() { }

  emitValue(value: number){
    this.change.next(value);
  }
}
```

Bottomsheet Controller:

```
@Component({
  selector: "bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet",
  templateUrl: "bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet.html"
})
export class BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet {
  constructor(
    private _bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet>,
    private service: SharedService
  ) { }

  manipulate() {
    console.log("DIV CLICKED");
    this.service.emitValue(99);
  }
}
```

App.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import {
  MatBottomSheet,
  MatBottomSheetRef
} from "@angular/material/bottom-sheet";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { SharedService } from "./shared.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  myCount: number = 0;
  constructor(
    private _bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) {
    this.sharedService.change.subscribe(value => {
      if (value) {
        console.log(value);
        this.myCount = value;
      }
    });
  }

  openBottomSheet(): void {
    this._bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet);
  }
}
```

[`Here`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxh97w) is the working demo:)

Comment: Works like a charm. You are right I was looking on this from wrong perspective.Thanks

Comment: Why not just an observable at the data?